# TCP download directly to storage

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, download

I've written a program that was initially intended for very basic text communication over the internet using the .net TCPClient class in C#. I decided to try setting up a procedure to read a file from one computer, break it up into smaller pieces which are each sent to the receiving computer, and have it reassembled and saved there. Essentially a file transfer.

I then realized that all the data I'm transferring is going into the memory of the receiving computer and then onto the storage in the next step. I am now wondering, is this the best way to do it? If data can be transferred and immediately written to the storage location where it's headed (bypassing the RAM step), is this the way a program like Google Chrome would handle downloads? Or are there usually important reasons for the data to be stored in memory first?

By the way, for clarity, let's all agree that "storage" would be like a hard drive and "memory" refers to RAM. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Th way it is done usually is you open a `FileStream` read data in `byte[]` from `TcpClient` and write the number of bytes read from `NetworkStream` to `FileStream`.

Here is a pseduso example :

```
TcpClient tcp;
FileStream fileStream = File.Open("WHERE_TO_SAVE", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
NetworkStream tcpStream = tcp.GetStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = tcpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
tcpStream.Dispose();
fileStream.Dispose();
```